# How do I automatically create an issue in a new GitHub repository?

Tags: ruby, github, octokit

I am the admin of a GitHub organization. I have set up a Repository webhook for the organization. I am using ngrok to communicate to a local sinatra instance. Here is my server.rb file:

```
require 'sinatra'
require 'json'

set :port, 1234

post '/payload' do
  push = JSON.parse(request.body.read)
  puts "I got some JSON: #{push.inspect}"
end
```

I receive a JSON payload when a repository is created. I would like to automatically create an issue in this new repository with a name and description. I'm assuming I need to use a gem to interact with GitHub API, so I chose octokit. I was able to authenticate, but I'm having trouble seeing how to interact with the API. I would like to create an issue in the newly created GitHub repository. Could I see some examples on ho this is used?

Reference:
https://developer.github.com/v3/issues/#create-an-issue

Answer (score 1):

```
Octokit.create_issue("sferik/rails_admin", 'Updated Docs', 'Added some extra links')
```

http://octokit.github.io/octokit.rb/Octokit/Client/Issues.html#create_issue-instance_method

Comment: Thanks for the link. I'm getting a 404. I'm guessing it has to do with my authenticating. Any ideas?

`Octokit::NotFound - GET https://api.github.com/authorizations/99: 404 - Not Found`  

`##login`  
`client = Octokit::Client.new(:login => 'username', :password => 'password')`
`client.authorization(99)`
`## create an issue in new repo with @mention`
`Octokit.create_issue("CodeAvenger07Organization/test", "New issue", "take a look @codeavenger07")`